# Filtering listview results when spinner values get selected

Tags: java, android, json

I have 3 spinners in my project named standard, division and age. They contain values from json data. When I select a value from each individual spinner it shows all data of students in a listview who are studying in that standard (fetched from JSON).

I'm working with the following JSON data:

```
[
{
"name":"aaa",
"surname":"bbb",
"age":"18",
"div":"A",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"ccc",
"surname":"ddd",
"age":"17",
"div":"B",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"eee",
"surname":"fff",
"age":"18",
"div":"A",
"standard":"8"
},
{
"name":"ggg",
"surname":"hhh",
"age":"17",
"div":"A",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"sss",
"surname":"ddd",
"age":"18",
"div":"A",
"standard":"8"
},
{
"name":"www",
"surname":"ggg",
"age":"17",
"div":"A",
"standard":"7"
},
{
"name":"ggg",
"surname":"ccc",
"age":"18",
"div":"B",
"standard":"6"
}
```

I am trying to do it like this way:

1. When I select standard 7 from the spinner it should display students information studying in 7th standard ("aaa", "ccc", "ggg", "www") and their other information too.
2. Then I am selecting value from division spinner say "A", it should take above result granted and accordingly display students from standard 7 and division "A". It currently shows the result as ("aaa", "ggg", "www") and their other informations too.
3. Finally, I am selecting value from age spinner say "17", it should take above result granted and accordingly display students from standard 7 and division "A" and age "17". Accordingly it shows "ggg" and "www".

I don't want like the way I did my code. Can anyone please assist me so it is more robust?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> AllStandards = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> AllDivision = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> AllAge = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsonArray;
Spinner spinner_std, spinner_div, spinner_age;
private ArrayList<StudInfo> studentVOList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final List<String> item_Std = getStandard("data.json");
final List<String> items_div = getDivision("data.json");
final List<String> items_age = getAge("data.json");

/*spinner for standard*/
spinner_std = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStandard);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_std = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_standard_layout, R.id.textViewStandard, item_Std);

spinner_std.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        try {

            String standard = AllStandards.get(i);

            if (studentVOList.size() > 0)
                studentVOList.clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String stand = jsonObject.getString("standard");
                if (stand.equalsIgnoreCase(standard)) {
                    StudInfo studentVO = new StudInfo();

                    studentVO.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    studentVO.setSurname(jsonObject.getString("surname"));
                    studentVO.setAge(jsonObject.getString("age"));
                    studentVO.setDiv(jsonObject.getString("div"));
                    studentVO.setStandard(jsonObject.getString("standard"));

                    studentVO.setStandard(stand);
                    studentVOList.add(studentVO);
                }
            }
            // Log.d("TAG", "List With All Students in selected standard: " + studentVOList.size());

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentsInfo.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("list", studentVOList);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
spinner_std.setAdapter(adapter_std);

/*spinner for division*/
spinner_div = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDiv);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_div = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_division_layout, R.id.textViewDivision, items_div);

spinner_div.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        try {

            String division = AllDivision.get(i);

            if (studentVOList.size() > 0)
                studentVOList.clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String div = jsonObject.getString("div");
                // Collections.sort(AllDivision);

                if (div.equalsIgnoreCase(division)) {
                    StudInfo studentVO = new StudInfo();

                    studentVO.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    studentVO.setSurname(jsonObject.getString("surname"));
                    studentVO.setAge(jsonObject.getString("age"));
                    studentVO.setStandard(jsonObject.getString("standard"));
                    studentVO.setDiv(jsonObject.getString("div"));

                    studentVO.setDiv(div);
                    studentVOList.add(studentVO);
                }
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentsInfo.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("list", studentVOList);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", b);

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
spinner_div.setAdapter(adapter_div);

/*spinner for age*/
spinner_age = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinerAge);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_age = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_age_layout, R.id.textViewAge, items_age);

spinner_age.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        try {

            String age = AllAge.get(i);

            if (studentVOList.size() > 0)
                studentVOList.clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String age_list = jsonObject.getString("age");
                Collections.sort(AllAge);

                if (age_list.equalsIgnoreCase(age)) {
                    StudInfo studentVO = new StudInfo();

                    studentVO.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    studentVO.setSurname(jsonObject.getString("surname"));
                    studentVO.setDiv(jsonObject.getString("div"));
                    studentVO.setStandard(jsonObject.getString("standard"));
                    studentVO.setAge(jsonObject.getString("age"));

                    studentVO.setAge(age_list);
                    studentVOList.add(studentVO);
                }
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentsInfo.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("list", studentVOList);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", b);

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
spinner_age.setAdapter(adapter_age);

}//onCreate Method

private List<String> getStandard(String fileName) {
jsonArray = null;
try {
    InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    is.read(data);
    is.close();
    String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");

    // AllStandards.clear();
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String stand = jsonObject.getString("standard");

            if (!AllStandards.contains(stand)) {
                AllStandards.add(stand);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        je.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return AllStandards;
}

private List<String> getDivision(String fileName) {
jsonArray = null;
try {
    InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    is.read(data);
    is.close();
    String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String stand = jsonObject.getString("div");
            if (!AllDivision.contains(stand)) {
                AllDivision.add(stand);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        je.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return AllDivision;
}

private List<String> getAge(String fileName) {
jsonArray = null;
try {
    InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    is.read(data);
    is.close();
    String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String stand = jsonObject.getString("age");
            if (!AllAge.contains(stand)) {
                AllAge.add(stand);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        je.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return AllAge;
}
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StudInfo> {
int vg;
ArrayList<StudInfo> list;
Context context;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, ArrayList<StudInfo> list) {
super(context, vg, id, list);
this.context = context;
this.vg = vg;
this.list = list;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View itemView = inflater.inflate(vg, parent, false);

TextView textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
TextView textViewSurname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
TextView textViewAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
TextView textViewDiv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDiv);
TextView textViewStd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStandard);

textViewName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
textViewSurname.setText(list.get(position).getSurname());
textViewAge.setText(list.get(position).getAge());
textViewDiv.setText(list.get(position).getDiv());
textViewStd.setText(list.get(position).getStandard());

return itemView;
}
}
```

**StudentsInfo.java**

```
public class StudentsInfo extends Activity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.studentsinfo_layout);

Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");

ArrayList<StudInfo> studentVOList = (ArrayList<StudInfo>) b.getSerializable("list");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShow);
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, R.id.txtName, studentVOList);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
}
```